# Force yum dependency update only if installed

Tags: rpm, yum, rpm-spec

I have a number for RPM packages.  One package is the main package that is always installed.  The other packages are optional and provide some additional features.  I want to ensure that these packages remain in sync with regards to Software version.  If the main RPM packages is updated with 'yum update mypackage' I would like to force the optional packages to update as well, but **only if they are installed**.

I looked into putting in the RPM SPEC file:

```
Requires: optionalPackage1 >= 3.4.5
```

where the version would be my current mainPackage version (all packages will have same version).  But my understanding is that this will always install optionalPackage1 if it is not currently installed when **yum update mainPackage** is used.

What I would like is to add something in the SPEC file of the sort:

```
RequiresIfInstalled: optionalPackage1 > 3.4.5
RequiresIfInstalled: optionalPackage2 > 3.4.5
RequiresIfInstalled: optionalPackage3 > 3.4.5
```

Then if I do:

```
yum update mainPackage
```

and optionalPackage1 is installed but at version 3.4.1, it will update to 3.4.5, but if optionalPackage2 is not installed it will not be installed at this time.

Is there any way to specify this in an RPM SPEC file?

Comment: any updates on this? If any of these answers helped you, please upvote. If any answer solves your problem, please mark the solution.

Answer (score 1):

since the numbering of your main package and optional packages evolve together, may I assume that they are produced by the same `spec` file? In that case I would just turn the dependencies around.

In the spec file:

```
name: main-package

%package -n optionalPackage1
Requires %{name} = %{version}-%{release}
```

in this way, the optional packages will require to be installed with the main package with the exact same version. So when both scenarios will work:

- updating the main package alone will work
- updating the main package while `optionalPackage1` is installed, will force the update of `optionalPackage1` to the exact same version.

**NOTE**: you can apply this method also when your main and optional packages don't reside in the same repository, but that would mean that you would need to apply changes in all spec for all optional packages each time you generate a new **main** package.

**NOTE2**: this won't work with `>=` because then updating main package from 1.2.3 to 2.0.0 won't force the update for `optionalPackage1` which requires `main >= 1.2.3`...
If you don't want exact requirements you could opt for some kind of "range" strategy, something like:

```
Requires: main >= 1.2
Requires: main < 1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

RPM has the concept of "[recommends](https://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html)" but it's fairly new and I'm not sure what distributions support it. Fedora [mentions it in the Packaging Guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:WeakDependencies) without any versioning info.